# webViewDidFinishLoad in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have to migrate from UIWebView to WKWebView and I'm having some trouble with this. It looks like that "WKWebView" has no member 'request'. Is there a way to handle this situation using the WKWebView? I simply need to get the URL loaded and then if it contains ".pdf" just show a button.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView : WKWebView) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

    if (webView.request?.url!.absoluteString)!.range(of: ".pdf") != nil {
        pdfBackButton.isHidden = false
    }
    else {
    pdfBackButton.isHidden = true}

}
```

Comment: Try `webView.url` More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342546/wkwebview-full-url

Comment: @toddg unfortunately it is not enough and if I want to print the current URL by doing print(webView.url) it does'nt work...

Answer (score 11):

Add `"WebKit"` framework to your class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     let myWebView:WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
     myWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
     let url = URL(string: "https://www.Apple.com")!
     myWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
     self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
}
```

then implement `WKNavigationDelegate` method

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    let url = webView.url
    print(url as Any) // this will print url address as option field
    if url?.absoluteString.range(of: ".pdf") != nil {
         pdfBackButton.isHidden = false
         print("PDF contain")
    }
    else {
         pdfBackButton.isHidden = true
         print("No PDF Contain")        
    } 
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: If I put this line "myWebView.navigationDelegate = self;" the application instantly crashes when starting. I've read that it is not possible anymore to use this with the WKWebView.... could be this the problem? If I use your code without that line I can run it but I then have the same problem: the function didFinish looks like it is never called. Infact I don't see the URLs loaded....

Comment: I have tried this and it is working fine..! looks like you are missing out something..

Comment: send me crash report or log so that i can analyse it help you to resolve the issue...!!

Comment: @ernestocattaneo I was having the same problem, but figured it out.  I had inserted the UIView using a storyboard and forgot to delete it and reinsert the WKWebView instead.  Once I did that the above code worked like a champ.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement the [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate) [webView(_:didFinish:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview) function.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    let url = webView.url

    if url?.absoluteString.range(of: ".pdf") != nil {
        pdfBackButton.isHidden = false
    }
    else {
        pdfBackButton.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but unfortunately it doesn't work... I added a simple "print(url!)" after the declaration of the url but the current url loaded is never printed in the console and so I guess that this method is never called... any idea on that?

Comment: Did you set the WKWebView delegate?

Comment: @toddg I'm actually having problem on this I guess. When I set "webView.navigationDelegate = self" in the "viewDidLoad" method, then my application crashes on startup...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784033/simple-webview-navigationdelegate-crashes-on-start I've created this other question regarding the delegate :)