# Simple Webview: navigationDelegate crashes on start

Tags: ios, webview, swift3, appdelegate, wkwebview

I have a small problem with my WebView. This is what I do in my app:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,  WKNavigationDelegate  {

@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView! // draged from storyboard

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var urlToLoad : (String)
    urlToLoad = "http://wwww.myapp.com"

    webView.sizeToFit()
    webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let url = URL(string: urlToLoad)
    let request = URLRequest(url:url!)
    //webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.load(request)
}
```

As you see the row "webView.navigationDelegate = self" is commented. If I uncomment it my app will crash on start and telling me this:

***Debugger***: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

[image]

Any idea of why is this happening and how to solve this? I need this in order to use methods like "didFinish navigation" that I already implemented in the page but they are never called.

Also, by having a look at my code... you see anything I should change regarding the use of my webview?

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: "WKWebView! do I need this?": Yes

Comment: @shallowThought so I rebinded the storyboard creating the IBOutlet but the problem is always the same

Comment: I suspect you did bind it to something that is not a WKWebView.

Comment: @Infact when I drag the webview it creates the bound but as a UIWebView and then I manually changed it to WkWebView... how can I bind it as WkWebView?

Answer (score 2):

You are using UIWebView and trying to call the methods of WKWebView which is leading to crash your app due to unrecognised selector send on UIWebView.

Try to create new project and use below mentioned code.

import "WebKit" framework to your class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 let myWebView:WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
 myWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
 let url = URL(string: "https://www.Apple.com")!
 myWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
 self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
}
```

then implement WKNavigationDelegate method

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
let url = webView.url
print(url as Any) // this will print url address as option field
if url?.absoluteString.range(of: ".pdf") != nil {
     pdfBackButton.isHidden = false
     print("PDF contain")
   }
else {
     pdfBackButton.isHidden = true
     print("No PDF Contain")        
   } 
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

You are binding an `UIWebView` to a property of type `WKWebView`. As a result it crashes when trying to call `navigationDelegate` on the `UIWebView`, as it does not offer this method.

There is no template version of WKWebView available in Storyboard, so you have to create the `WKWebView` programatically:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,  WKNavigationDelegate  {

var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view.addSubview(webView)

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
}
```

Comment: thank you for trying to help me but unfortunately this doesn't work. I tried by opening a fresh new project and simply do what you said but no luck... look: http://imgur.com/a/eZTSJ

Comment: by programatically you mean that I only have to write the code into the ViewController without creating the View in the Storyboard and then bounding it? Is it enough to just put this code? Because now the naked app that I created to test this works but it isnt showing me anything. Cheers buddy

Comment: You mean that I also have to create a new .swift file linked to this new MyViewController? Or you mean linking this MyViewController to the actual ViewController.swift?

Comment: Click this link to find download link to example project: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128967/discussion-between-shallowthought-and-ernestocattaneo

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize the `webView`. The app crashes because it's `nil`.

You need to bind it to the storyboard or the xib file (uncomment the `@IBOutlet`) or initialize it programmatically and then add it to you `viewController's` `view`.

Comment: I binded the storyboard creating the IBOutlet but the problem is always the same...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error `Value of type '(WKWebView, WKNavigation?) -> ()' has no member 'navigationDelegate'` (which I'm guessing was the same issue as what was causing the crash when adding `webView.navigationDelegate = self`).

I found that the view controller class needs to implement the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol (kinda like inheritance) by adding it to the class definition, which fixed the error for me. Make sure to have that as in the first line of this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
  // ...

  override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
  }

  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
     // ...
  }      
}
```