# In Xcode (Mac), How to make textfield update to WebView URL (Cocoa)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, webview

in Xcode, I am working on a browser. (for desktop)

So far, I have a basic one. I am very new to Xcode.

How do I make the TextField (where you type the URL) update to what the URL the web viewer is currently viewing?

For example, if you type in *stackoverflow.com* in chrome and start clicking on stuff, the text field above will change and not stay as *stackoverflow.com* like mine does.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WKWebView full URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342546/wkwebview-full-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement `WKNavigationDelegate`'s `decidePolicyFor:navigationAction:decisionHandler:` and retreive the URL there.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {
    textField.text = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString

    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

**Note:** you must apply the delegate to the WKWebView, like this:

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```